# Rails 3 + jQuery Mobile Themeroller = Invalid CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, themeroller

Using a custom jQuery Mobile theme created via Themeroller works fine with Rails for local development. However, running:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

on the production server results in this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...gradient(linear": expected ")", was ",left top,left ..."
```

With that line of code in custom-theme.min.css being:

```
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from( #333333 ),to( #333333 ));
```

The custom theme is included in application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min
 *= require custom-theme.min
 *= require jquery-mobile-fluid960.min
```

I believe the generated Themeroller syntax is valid... Does it have something to do with the css/sass/scss combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the jQuery Mobile Themeroller can be a little buggy. If gradients and borders are not set—that is, omitting the hex color code—it still generates the # tag but no color code, or appends 'NaN' to the end of a gradient color. Setting all colors in Themeroller and then a simple search for `border:1px solid # ;` and replace on the generated *.min.css file cleaned this up.